# Two separate windows displaying two buttons from the program using PySide6.QtWidgets

Tags: python-3.x, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyside6

I wrote this code in python using PySide6, but the output of this code is producing 2 different windows, holding the buttons. Where am I going wrong? I want both the buttons to be one after the other. How do I do this?

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *

class buttonHolder(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        button = QPushButton("hiya!")
        self.setCentralWidget(button)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = buttonHolder()
window.show()

newbutton = QPushButton("yoyo")
newbutton.show()


app.exec()
```

I tried this and was expecting to have buttons one after the other, much like how you get in Tkinter, but I seem to have gone wrong somewhere. Please help